# How to load data from database to Spark before filtering

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run such a PySpark application:

```
with SparkSession.builder.appName(f"Spark App").getOrCreate() as spark:
    dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
        url="jdbc:mysql://.../...",
        driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
        dbtable='my_table',
        user=...,
        password=...,
        partitionColumn='id',
        lowerBound=0,
        upperBound=10000000,
        numPartitions=11,
        fetchsize=1000000,
        isolationLevel='NONE'
    ).load()

    dataframe_mysql = dataframe_mysql.filter("date > '2022-01-01'")
    dataframe_mysql.write.parquet('...')
```

And I found that Spark didn't load data from Mysql until executing the `write`, this means that Spark let the database take care of filtering the data, and the SQL that database received may like:

```
select * from my_table where id > ... and id< ... and date > '2022-01-01'
```

My table was too big and there's no index on `date` column, the database couldn't handle the filtering. How can I load data into Spark's memory before filtering, I hope the query sent to the databse could be:

```
select * from my_table where id > ... and id< ...
```

Comment: it's called predicate pushdown which pushes the filters to data source if possible. why do you think your db can't handle the filter?

Comment: [this JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24288) about preventing pushdown was resolved and it shares the resolution in its description.

Comment: @samkart Because this application has caused deadlock in the database. I'll read this ticket, thank you

Comment: Hi @samkart I've read the ticket and found they mentioned to add a new option for jdbc named `pushDownPredicate `, but I can't find this option in Spark documentation

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#:~:text=read-,pushDownPredicate,-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @samkart's comment, set `pushDownPredicate` to False could solve this problem